# how do i add autoplay to a livestream video in script

Tags: video, stream, autoplay

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://www.telemundopr.com/portableplayer/?cmsID=322531692&videoID=98lWvcJOLJbw&lvshell=322531692&origin=telemundopr.com&sec=noticias&subsec=puerto-rico&fullWidth=y"></script>
```

I would like to add an `autoplay` option to this script.

I've tried adding: `?autoplay=1`, `video tag` and `iframe`.

Comment: Were did you find the player? Does it say in manual that it has `autoplay`? Did you explore the source code (find the "play" and "load" functions and also on same JS file there should be "load a video" logic that can possibly be told to autoplay)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Video Autoplay in popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175166/youtube-video-autoplay-in-popup)